# Pulling of Light by a Black Hole?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, black-holes, photons, mass

We all know that light has **no mass** at all. Yet we say that the gravitational pull of a Blackhole within Schwarzschild radius doesn't let light to pass. If the light has no mass, how can it experience the force? Secondly, does this phenomena suggest the particle nature of light?

Answer (score 1):

Light doesn't really experience a force due to gravity; it's just that light follows "null geodesics" in curved space. Curvature of space is caused by the presence of mass/energy.   A geodesic is a curve that takes the shortest path between two points.

The particle or wave nature of light does not influence the way gravity affects light, at least under any conditions currently accessible to experiments.